# DbUpdateException when adding entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to add many test-entities when my database is seeded and I am running into a DbUpdateException with the following constellation:

```
public class Law
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    // a law in my context is just a container of LawVersions
    public virtual IList<LawVersion> Versions {get;set;}
}

public class LawVersion
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual Law Law {get; set;}
    public string CreationNote {get;set;}
    public DateTime CreationDate {get;set;}

    public LawVersion() 
    {
        CreationDate = DateTime.Now
    }
}
```

I can successfully add laws to my database using this list of laws in my seed method:

```
var Laws = new List<Law>()
{
    var Law = new Law()
    { 
        Versions= new List<LawVersion>()
        {
            new LawVersion()
            {
                Name = "Constituiton",
                CreationNote = "initial version",
                CreationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-38155)
            },
            new LawVersion()
            {
                Name = "Constitution",
                CreationNote = "changed the typo in Name",
                CreationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-38154)
            }
        }
    },
    // more laws
}

// add Laws to the database, will add LawVersions as well
Laws.ForEach(x => db.Laws.Add(x)
db.SaveChanges();
```

The following, however, will result in a DbUpdateException on the second loop, and I don't understand why:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    // DbUpdateException on second loop
    Laws.ForEach(x => db.Laws.Add(x)
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

The exception states that

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. (...). Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0).

I've got this working for another entity and I cant see any differences between them. I would be very thankful for a hint.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Pre-populating data?

Comment: Yes, I would like to add e.g. 1000 data samples (their content plays no role) to get a grip of e.g. loading times.

Comment: Is your ID column auto-generated?

Comment: Yes it is auto-generated.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely due to the fact your are trying to re-add entities which already exist in the database. Please try the following to copy the existing entities to new objects before saving:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    foreach (var l in Laws) 
    {
        db.Laws.Add(new Law
        {
            Name = l.Name,
            CreationNote = l.CreationNote,
            CreationDate = l.CreationDate
        });
    }
}
db.SaveChanges();
```